# How to get text off of Flutter Webview Plugin

Tags: flutter, web-scraping

I am using the flutter webview plugin to try to webscrape a link off of a website that requires a login. Once the user logins and gets redirected, I want to access the contents of the website. Is it possible to do this directly in the webview plugin?

Answer (score 0):

First you can execute javascript by `evalJavaScript` to fill the username / password. 
Then you can listen for `onUrlChanged` after the user redirect and get the content of the page you want.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm a bit more puzzled on how to get the contents of the page and store them into variables from the the webview. For example, there is text on one of the redirected websites and I want to get that text and store it into a string variable. Is there anyways to scrape that text in the webview plugin?

Comment: String text =  await flutterWebviewPlugin.evalJavaScript("document.querySelector('#element').innerText");

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_webview_plugin):

> Use `flutterWebviewPlugin.evalJavaScript(String code)`. This function must be run after the page has finished loading (i.e. listen to `onStateChanged` for events where state is finishLoad).
>
> If you have a large amount of JavaScript to embed, use an asset file.

Actually `evalJavaScript` returns a `Future<String>` so you have to `await` it or use `.then( () {} )` .

For example:

```dart
String data_from_webview =  await flutterWebviewPlugin.evalJavaScript("document.getElementById('#someElement').innerText");
```

Here are the [documentation](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await) of Futures and here is a good simple [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OTS-ap9_aXc) about Futures in dart.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Are there any examples on what to put into the  document.getElementById function? I'm having a bit of trouble to get my program to not return "null"

Comment: Well, you have to know a little bit of JavaScript in order to extract information from a website! You can use `document.querySelector()` with css selector as parameter , it is easier to deal with. And I can't give you an answer blindly, what's the website and what do you wanna extract?